# Delphi Invalid jarsign option warning

Tags: android, delphi

Delphi 10.2.3
Building for Android Application Store

I get this warning:

```
[PAClient Warning] Warning: W0020 Invalid jarsign option: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\JarSigner.exe,.\Android\Release\COWMobileBuild30\bin\COWMobileBuild30-unsigned.apk,cow android key alias,C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2433_19.0.29899.2631\tools\Mike's Google Keystore.keystore,MD5withRSA,SHA1,851C47C05F940783CF7DE53CD171E33F81850535A05F97C997AA0FF88E783C8ADB56A385E3111C2FC1E2577DFAC4C363BA95367E043722D3163A459DE5E4229DC938F341D558FA9BBFF8AF1172218595,851C47C0645855D8A342711DD129E36881D0051BA043979397B40FAB8E363C94DB04A3D7E3401C39C1CC5752FACFC338BAF83613042722C3164B45C2E5BA22DBC90AF35DEE8AA8C8D3DE3B1E72218595,1, ignored
```

Then the install fails with:

```
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Project|Options... Provisioning, clicking the Check Passwords buttons says:

> "Your keystore and certificate passwords are valid."

What am I missing?

Comment: `jarsign` is pretty old I would not use it anymore for app signing (I think it is deprecated for Android). Use `apksigner` from Android SDK instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jarsign or apksigner. Delphi does the signing in this case. If there's a manual way to sign a Delphi app with apksigner I'd like to hear more about it.

Comment: Try deleting the app from the device first

Comment: Before building for any Android device, I drag the app to the Uninstall icon. I assume that's enough to delete the app from the device.

Answer (score 0):

The warning about the invalid jarsign option apparently stemmed from naming my key file:

> Mike's Google Keystore.keystore

The apostrophe (or maybe the spaces) in the file name confused jarsign.

I changed the file name to:

> MikesGoogleKeystore.keystore

That got it to build and install successfully.

Comment: This is a clear delphi bug, not escaping the file name properly when forming the command line for jarsign. Submit a bug report.